# in laravel js production, I have a question about 405 error. but there is no slash in the tail of url

Tags: laravel, axios

I create ajax application with laravel and js(axios).

I hosted this on AWS.
in development, My app work well.
But not working in production.

http://ec2-18-181-225-61.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/
this is my app's url.

When I click delete button, the below error is displayed.

> main.js:67          DELETE http://ec2-18-181-225-61.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/posts/1/destroy 405 (Method Not Allowed)

The below code is main.js file.

```
/*ajax delete*/

deletes.forEach(span => {
    const postid = span.dataset.id;
    span.addEventListener('click', () => {

        fetch('/posts/'+ postid + '/destroy', {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': token,
            }
        });

        span.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
        const count = ul.childElementCount;

        if (count == 0) {
            ul.insertBefore(noLi, ul.firstChild);
        }
    })
});
```

```
// leftside.blade.php delete form

    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <div class="left-container">
            <div class="form-box">
                <h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 10px">RECIPE HOUSE</h4>
                <form method="post" class="add-form">
                    <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                            <input class="input title-input" type="text" name="title" placeholder="enter category name">
                            {{-- @error('title')
                            <div class="error">{{ $message }}</div>
                            @enderror --}}
                            <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>
                            </span>
                    </p>
                </form>
```

https://github.com/sakamotosora0116/recipehouse_laravel/
This is my all source code.

I searched website and I find other's solution(Don't write slash in the tail of url).
but That didn't apply to my case.

Could you please tell me another solution?

Thank you for your help.I am sorry my English is poor.

Comment: None of the URLs other than the homepage work for http://ec2-18-181-225-61.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com so this looks like a server configuration issue e.g. maybe you need to enable mod_rewrite for Apache

Comment: Thank you for giving me a good advice. I am reading apache document now.